# How to add Requiredfieldvalidator control to formview itemtemplate

Tags: asp.net

How to add(bind) Requiredfieldvalidator control to formview itemtemplate?

```
     <tr runat="server" > 
         <td style="width: 120px">

             <asp:Label Text="Purchase Org.:" ID="LabelPurchOrg1" runat="server">  </asp:Label>
       </td>
        <td>
            <orbit:Control runat="server" ID="Purch" Text='<%# Eval("Site")%>'                    LabelPosition="Right" CssClassLabel="SectionTextLookup"   RenderTextBoxAsLabel="true" EnableLabel="true" EnableTooltip="true" LookupCommand="sit" />

           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PurchaseOrg" runat="server" ControlToValidate='<%#   Eval("Site") %>'   ErrorMessage="<" EnableClientScript="false" Enabled="false" >
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Are you trying to validate <orbit:Control runat="server" ID="Purch" Text='<%# Eval("Site")%>'?, if so then simply use "Purch" in the ControlToValidate="Purch".

Answer (score 0):

So you just need to change the RequiredFieldValidator as below:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PurchaseOrg" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="Purch" ErrorMessage="<" EnableClientScript="false" 
Enabled="false" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: <orbit:Control runat="server" ID="Purch" Text='<%# Eval("Site")%>'